# Bus error 10 in C: string literals

Tags: c

Can someone explain why

```
 char *s1 = "abcd";
 char *s2 = s1;
 s1[0] = "z";
 s1[2] = "\0";
```

gives me a bus error 10 BUT

```
 char s1[] = "abcd";
 char *s2 = s1;
 s1[0] = "z";
 s1[2] = "\0";
```

doesn't?

are char *s1 and char s1[] not equivalent? Please explain, thanks.

Comment: "_are char *s1 and char s1[] not equivalent?_" -- No. Array != Pointer. You got that error because you aren't supposed to change a string literal and doing so results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: And Now that I take a closer look at what you are doing, it makes no sense. You are trying to store a string (`char*`) in a `char` variable. Keep in mind that `"..."` is a string while `'.'` is a character.

Answer (score 1):

### Be free (of historical lazyness), be wise! Pointers are not arrays! Tutorials have lied you!

In the first example, you're modifying a *pointer* to a *constant* string literal, and that's undefined behaviour. Anything can happen then!

Meanwhile, in the second case, the string itself is stored *inside the array*, and the array itself is *in the stack*. Thus, the second example exposes more than a plain innocent array that's modifiable.

The `s2` pointers make no difference in all this. IMHO, the fact that the first case is compilable is just historical lazyness, otherwise known as *backwards compatibility*.

**BTW**: Are you assigning *string literals* to `char`s? That's undefined behaviour too!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you set a s1 pointer to the address `const` string.  Const string are stored in read -only area and you cannot modify it. This means that you cannot modify a character `s[x]`. It is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

In the second case you declare a local array inited with a string. In this case only the init value is read-only and after init you use an allocated array that can be modified.