# Why is this C code getting a bus error? (No external functions allowed)

Tags: c, pointers, memory, bus

I've been working through this code for hours but couldn't locate the error. It passes the compiler, but while running it gets a bus error, why?

```
char    *ft_strrev(char *str);

char    *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int count;
    int d;
    char temp[5];

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    d = 0;
    while (str[count] != '\0')
    {
        count++;
    }
    while (d < count)
    {
        temp[d] = str[d];
            d++;
    }
    while (--count >= 0)
    {
        str[i] = temp[count];
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}

int main()
{
    char *pooch;
    pooch = "allo";
    ft_strrev(pooch);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Do not try to change the string literal.

Comment: Try `pooch = "allo";` --> `pooch = (char[]){"allo"};` or `char *pooch;
    pooch = "allo"` --> `char pooch[] = "allo"`

Comment: In C++11 and maybe C11(though i'm not sure), non const pointers to string literals are deprecated (make sure you're using the latest version of your compiler, and with compiler warnings on). Anyway, just remember that trying to write to memory allocated for a string literal is illegal and will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EatABagel  For each source string with different number of symbols you have to write a separate function.:)

Comment: How can I make this     char pooch[] = "allo"    in 2 lines, so to separate the declaration from the initialization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bus error 10 in C: string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664826/bus-error-10-in-c-string-literals)

Comment: Why would you want to separate declaration from initialization?  It's easier when you combine them.  If you must, then `char pooch[16]; strcpy(pooch, "allo");` or variations on that them.  You have to specify the size of the array (you could use `sizeof("allo")` instead of 16; 16 is deliberately over-allocating space), and then you have to copy data into it (so you need to include `<string.h>` too).  So much easier just to say `char pooch[] = "allo";`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is modifying the string. In the code you pass in a literal string. You should not change literal strings.

Instead use something like:

```
char pooch[5];
pooch[0] = 'a';
pooch[1] = 'l';
pooch[2] = 'l';
pooch[3] = 'o';
pooch[4] = 0;
ft_strrev(pooch);
return 0;
```

Comment: The OP was clear about **_no external functions allowed_**.

Comment: `pooch` can be initialised using `char pooch[] = "allo"`.   In that case, the string literal is used to initialise the array, but the array ca be modified.