# Getting bus error while adding ascii values to array characters. Why? (C)

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strupcase(char *str);

char    *ft_strupcase(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
             str[i] -= 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test = ft_strupcase("fdfFEhk");
    for (int k = 0; test[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
        printf("%c", test[k]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The expected result is to print the string passed to the function, all in capital letters. Instead, I get a bus error. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: You can't do it with a string literal. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: You cannot modify a constant ...

Comment: If you executes this program with a debugger you will discover that the instruction `str[i] -= 32;` will raise a segmentation fault at the first while loop cycle. This is 'cause the string `"fdfFEhk"` is a CONSTANT. Under the operating systems such as Linux or Windows this is an error. If you use this code under DOS it should run.

Comment: It is the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856233/why-is-this-c-code-getting-a-bus-error-no-external-functions-allowed). Why don't you read those answer?

Answer (score 3):

In your `ft_strupcase()` function, you're trying to modify the content of a [*string literal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To quote the standard, `C11`, chapter §6.4.5/P7, *String literals*

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

The argument you received is a string literal and you are not allowed to change the content. To avoid, you have to either

- Pass a modifiable memory as the actual argument.
- Inside the function, create a block (need to take care of the lifetime, either `static` storage or allocated via memory allocator functions), copy the content, perform the modify operations and return the address.

Comment: If you executes this program with a debugger you will discover that the instruction str[i] -= 32; will raise a segmentation fault at the first while loop cycle. This is 'cause the string "fdfFEhk" is a CONSTANT. Under the operating systems such as Linux or Windows this is an error. If you use this code under DOS it should run.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini that's why it is undefined behaviour. Sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini-- [The Standard explicitly states that it is undefined behavior to attempt to modify the contents of the array representing a string literal.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7)

Comment: @tilz0R Thanks for the follow up, I've added the reference into my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behaviour as you are modifying *[string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)* using `ft_strupcase` function

Rewrite your code to:

```
char source[] = "fdfFEhk";
char *test = ft_strupcase(source);
```

Now your string is not *string literal* anymore and is copied to RAM everytime `source` variable is initialized. Therefore, you have defined behaviour.

Comment: In the code written by @EatABagel the problem is that the string he uses is a costant, not an UB (IMHO).

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Trying to modify a constant is by definition undefined behaviour.

Comment: Under DOS it was possible. I'm just searching the old DOS compiler to see if it generates error, but is archeology!!! I think that is not undefined, but SO related. BTW is not a good style to modify constants.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini still, undefined behaviour. Period.

Comment: The error is generated by the CPU that doesn't accept you write on memory area declared read-only. This behaviour doesn't depend by the C-Language.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Im done talking here, sorry.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini-- it _is_ undefined behavior [according to the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7), which is the final word on the matter. That it appears to work may be a manifestation of UB; this is not proof that it is not UB. But, Microsoft is notoriously noncomformant.